# Rails - superclass refactoring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, superclass

I have 2 models, let's say `A` and `B`. They share some attributes, but they have also specific ones:

A has attributes => `SHARED_ATTR` and `A_ATTR`

B has attributes => `SHARED_ATTR` and `B_ATTR`

I need to use `paginate` and `acts_as_list` over arrays containing both `A` and `B` records, and i think the best way to make this possible is to create a supermodel `C` in a way such that

```
class C < ActiveRecord::Base
class A < C
class B < C
```

And i want to remove `A`'s and `B`'s tables, and copy their records in a new global `C` table, with `SHRED_ATTR`, `A_ATTR` and `B_ATTR`.

My question is:

**What is the best and fastest way to do this without losing A and B records?**

Comment: What is the reasoning behind creating a `C` table?

Comment: Because if i don't create it, how can i use "acts_as_list"?

Comment: You don't need to make a model to inherit code.

Comment: Hi Devin, my need is not only to inherit code. I need to use "acts_as_list" over an array with both A and B models. If you know a way to make this possible without creating a super model please let me know!